# Web cropping interface

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to emulate [avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)'s cropping interface on the Web.

[image: Poster with unwanted black margins]

[image: Mixing the colours since our crop has overrun]

In https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/msL6fjer/ I am using a container and overflow hidden trick to shrink away the black margins. But in this example if you accidentally go lower, you can't actually tell you're eating away at the blue content!

```
  <div :style="'height:' + height + 'px'" class="container">
    <img :style="'margin-top: ' + margin + 'px'" width=200 height=200 src=http://s.natalian.org/2016-11-04/200test.png alt="200x200 image with an unwanted margin of 50 either side">
  </div>
```

I re-wrote that example to use clip-path, which frustratingly only seems to work in Chrome 56, but nowhere else! https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/nmkh9d39/ This also has the issue of not knowing when you've overshot. Ideally the adjustable red layer grows & when it goes over the blue, the blue+red makes magenta or something like that.

Any tips how to achieve what I want in CSS or SVG? Please feel free to choose different colours!

Comment: To save everyone from downloading and installing avidemux, can you explain what exactly you want to happen? How it should behave?

Comment: Was hoping the images I included were explanatory. I want to be able to tell when I overcrop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shutter effect that you are after is fairly easy to achieve with SVG.

Here's one way.  We create the "shutter" by using two semi-transparent rectangles.  Note that I have built my example with jQuery since I am not familiar with Vue.

```js
$slider = $("#slider");

$slider.on("input", update);

function update(evt) {

  var margin = parseInt($slider.val(), 10);
  var top = -margin;
  var bottom = 200 + margin;
  var height = bottom - top;

  $("#margin").text(margin);
  $("#height").text(height);
  $("#toprect").attr("y", top - 100);
  $("#bottomrect").attr("y", bottom);
}

update();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg width="200" height="200">
  <image width="200" height="200" xlink:href="http://s.natalian.org/2016-11-04/200test.png"/>

  <rect id="toprect" y="-100" width="200" height="100" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
  <rect id="bottomrect" y="200" width="200" height="100" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
</svg>

<div>
  <label>Margin: <span id="margin"></span></label><br>
  <input id="slider" type="range" max="0" min="-100" value="0"><br>
  <label>Height: <span id="height"></span></label>
</div>
```

However, in your mockup, your shutter was blended with the background image to create merged colours.  We can achieve that effect using an SVG filter.

Here, instead of using `<rect>` elements, we create the shutter elements using two `<feFlood>` filter primitives. They allow us to create rectangles of colour which we can then blens with the `<image>` element we are applying the filter to.

First, just for comparison, here is the exact equivalent of the first sample, implemented using a filter.

```js
$slider = $("#slider");

$slider.on("input", update);

function update(evt) {

  var margin = parseInt($slider.val(), 10);
  var top = -margin;
  var bottom = 200 + margin;
  var height = bottom - top;

  $("#margin").text(margin);
  $("#height").text(height);
  $("#toprect").attr("y", top - 100);
  $("#bottomrect").attr("y", bottom);
}

update();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shutter" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feFlood id="toprect" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" flood-color="red" flood-opacity="0.5"
               result="part1"/>
      <feFlood id="bottomrect" x="0" y="100" width="200" height="100" flood-color="red" flood-opacity="0.5"
               result="part2"/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        <feMergeNode in="part1"/>
        <feMergeNode in="part2"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <image width="200" height="200" xlink:href="http://s.natalian.org/2016-11-04/200test.png"
         filter="url(#shutter)"/>
</svg>

<div>
  <label>Margin: <span id="margin"></span></label><br>
  <input id="slider" type="range" max="0" min="-100" value="0"><br>
  <label>Height: <span id="height"></span></label>
</div>
```

Now to achieve your blending effect, we need to change the way we combine the shutter elements with the image.  We do that with the `<feBlend mode="screen">` filter primitive.

```js
$slider = $("#slider");

$slider.on("input", update);

function update(evt) {

  var margin = parseInt($slider.val(), 10);
  var top = -margin;
  var bottom = 200 + margin;
  var height = bottom - top;

  $("#margin").text(margin);
  $("#height").text(height);
  $("#toprect").attr("y", top - 100);
  $("#bottomrect").attr("y", bottom);
}

update();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shutter" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feFlood id="toprect" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" flood-color="red" flood-opacity="0.5"
               result="part1"/>
      <feFlood id="bottomrect" x="0" y="100" width="200" height="100" flood-color="red" flood-opacity="0.5"
               result="part2"/>
      <feBlend mode="screen" in="SourceGraphic" in2="part1"/>
      <feBlend mode="screen" in2="part2"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <image width="200" height="200" xlink:href="http://s.natalian.org/2016-11-04/200test.png"
         filter="url(#shutter)"/>
</svg>

<div>
  <label>Margin: <span id="margin"></span></label><br>
  <input id="slider" type="range" max="0" min="-100" value="0"><br>
  <label>Height: <span id="height"></span></label>
</div>
```

**Update: solution for `<video>`**

You didn't mention that you wanted to achieve this over live video.  For that you would need a slightly different solution because the `<video>` element is not supported in the current SVG 1.1 standard.  It will likely be in the upcoming SVG 2 standard though.

Luckily it doesn't require a big change to support video. You just need to have the `<video>` element in your HTML. You can still apply an SVG filter to it.

This will work in some browsers. For example Chrome and Firefox, but not in others like IE11.

```js
$slider = $("#slider");

$slider.on("input", update);

function update(evt) {

  var margin = parseInt($slider.val(), 10);
  var top = -margin;
  var bottom = 200 + margin;
  var height = bottom - top;

  $("#margin").text(margin);
  $("#height").text(height);
  $("#toprect").attr("y", top - 100);
  $("#bottomrect").attr("y", bottom);
}

update();
```

```css
video {
  filter: url(#shutter);
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shutter" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feFlood id="toprect" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" flood-color="red" flood-opacity="0.5"
               result="part1"/>
      <feFlood id="bottomrect" x="0" y="100" width="200" height="100" flood-color="red" flood-opacity="0.5"
               result="part2"/>
      <feBlend mode="screen" in="SourceGraphic" in2="part1"/>
      <feBlend mode="screen" in2="part2"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

</svg>

<div class="container">
  <video width="200" height="200" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
         autoplay loop></video>
</div>

<div>
  <label>Margin: <span id="margin"></span></label><br>
  <input id="slider" type="range" max="0" min="-100" value="0"><br>
  <label>Height: <span id="height"></span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I used an image to make it simple, but I am trying to use this on a video and changing the image tag to video doesn't appear to work: https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/xeys63gu/ The video which has extraoneous black border is http://s.natalian.org/2016-11-10/outputfile.mp4

Comment: `<video>` will likely be in SVG 2, but it is not a valid element in SVG 1.1, which is the current standard that web browsers support.

Comment: Oh damn... efforts feel wasted :}

Comment: No it's not the end of the world. You can still do it. You just have to move the videl element out of the SVG. See updated answer.

Comment: You can likely also do it using `mix-blend-mode` if you prefer not to use the SVG approach.

Comment: Could you please explain the SVG part1/part2 stuff, since I want to introduce cropping from the sides and I am unable to figure it out! https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/fmus050t/1/

Comment: Futhermore why doesn't the video go fullscreen in https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/fmus050t/2/ ?

Comment: I'm not sure you what you mean by "the part1/part2 stuff". What do you not understand?  You should read [the section of the SVG spec on filters](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#chapter-filters) if you want to understand more about how they work.  `result="part1"` is giving the output of that filter component a name, which we can later refer to as the input to other filter components.

Comment: The video **is** going full screen. It is just that you are only seeing the very top left 200x200 section because that is the size of the filter.  See the `width` and `height` attributes on the `<filter>` element.  If you want to see the whole video in full screen, then remove the filter, or apply a modified one designed for the size of the full screen.

Comment: Thanks Paul.. sorry I managed to incorporate other parts into the blend. https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/fmus050t/4/ Still puzzled how to do fullscreen. First bind the event and set width height to what?

Comment: You'll need to read the width and height of the screen - or perhaps the video element.  If you want the "shutters" to display full screen also, then you'll probably want to update their sizes also.  Remember you could also define a different filter to be used for full screen - instead of modifying the original one.